How to sort WooCommerce variable products from max variation price in a custom query
I am trying to sort WooCommerce variable products from maximum variation price (my website contains simple and variable products).
My custom query below is sorting products by price, but the issue is that it is picking up the minimum variation price from variable products. Is there any way to sort them by maximum variation price instead?
function products_load_more() { 
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $strength = $_POST['strength'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $taxonomy_id = $_POST['taxonomy_id'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $amount1 = (int) $_POST['amount1'];
    $amount2 = (int) $_POST['amount2'];
    $sorting = $_POST['sorting'];
    $range_slider_array = array(0=>0,1=>100,2=>200,3=>300,4=>400,5=>500,6=>600,7=>700,8=>800,9=>900,10=>1000,11=>1500,12=>2000,13=>2500,14=>3000,15=>3500,16=>4000,17=>4500,18=>5000);
    
    if($sorting == "h_t_l"){
        $order = "DESC";
    }
    else{
        $order = "ASC";
    } 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_id
        ) )
    );  
    
    // price
    if(isset($_POST['amount1']) && isset($_POST['amount2'])){
        if(trim($amount1) != "" && trim($amount2) != ""){
            if($range_slider_array[$amount2] == 5000){
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'value' => $range_slider_array[$amount1],
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'  
                );
            } 
            else{
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'value' => array($range_slider_array[$amount1], $range_slider_array[$amount2]),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                );
            }
        }
    }
    
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
    
    $ajaxposts = new WP_Query($args);
    $count = $ajaxposts->found_posts;
    $response = '';

    if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
        while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
            include get_stylesheet_directory()."/inc/product.php";
        endwhile;
    } else {
        $response = 0;
    }
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_products_load_more', 'products_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_products_load_more', 'products_load_more');


sorting by _price should include variation price

Hi Gavin please give me some example

Take a look at WC_Query order_by_price_asc_post_clauses() method which is hooked to post_clause filter hook and filter the price from wp_wc_product_meta_lookup table min_price column (used by WooCommerce ordering by price). In this table, you have also max_price column, which you have to use instead. So you have to build your own function hooked to post_clause filter hook, in order to filter prices from max_price. This is the only way for variable products, instead of using a meta_query.

WC_Query order_by_price_asc_post_clauses() method

    function sort_products_by_max_variation_price($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !is_shop()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_min_variation_price',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ));

    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');

    $query->set('meta_key', 'max_price');

    // Add a join clause to include maximum variation prices
    add_filter('posts_join', function($join) use ($wpdb) {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT post_parent, MAX(meta_value+0) as max_price
            FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
            WHERE meta_key = '_price'
            GROUP BY post_parent
        ) as max_price_table ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = max_price_table.post_parent";
        return $join;
    });

    // Add a select clause to include maximum variation prices in the query
    add_filter('posts_fields', function($fields) use ($wpdb) {
        $fields .= ", max_price_table.max_price as max_price";
        return $fields;
    });

    // Add an orderby clause to sort by maximum variation prices
    add_filter('posts_orderby', function($orderby) use ($wpdb) {
        $orderby = "max_price DESC, {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC";
        return $orderby;
    });
} 
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_products_by_max_variation_price');

